# Reflection in Java -- unexpected output

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing a class to get information about a specified class using reflection. The output includes the fully qualified method name and I do not want the fully qualified name in the output.

Here's an example. Instead of:

```
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int,int)
```

I want it to display:

```
public static String toString(int, int);
```

Here is a simplified version of my class:

```
public class jr
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        jr j = new jr();

        String str = java.lang.Integer;

        Class cls = Class.forName(str);
        j.print(cls);   
    }

   /*
    * Displays the Methods of the given class. The items displayed depends on 
    * the options entered.
    *
    * @param    cl    The class to be displayed
    */ 
    public void methods(Class cl)
    {
        // Get the Methods of the Class cl
        Method[] me = cl.getDeclaredMethods();

        for(Method x : me)
        {            
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }

   /*
    * Displays the information about the class. Uses the options to filter which
    * information is printed.
    *
    * @param    cl    The class to be displayed
    */         
    public void print(Class cl)
    {
        System.out.println("\nMETHODS:");
        methods(cl);
    }
}
```

I could always just parse the String to clean it up but that seems like a bit of a hack. I don't see any better way of doing it though.

Comment: You're going to have to write your parser to parse the `Method` to the format that you want.  Take a closer look at the [`Method` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you modify methods as below :

```
public void methods(Class cl) {
    // Get the Methods of the Class cl
    Method[] me = cl.getDeclaredMethods();

    for (Method x : me) {
        String parameterType = "";
        System.out.println(x);
        Class[] parameterTypes = x.getParameterTypes();
        for (Class c : parameterTypes)
        parameterType = parameterType + c.getSimpleName() + " ,";

        System.out.println(x.getModifiers() + " " + x.getReturnType().getSimpleName() + " " + x.getName() + " ( "
            + parameterType + " )");
    }
    }
```

**Output**
METHODS:

```
public int java.lang.Integer.hashCode()
1 int hashCode (  )
public boolean java.lang.Integer.equals(java.lang.Object)
1 boolean equals ( Object , )
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int)
9 String toString ( int , )
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int,int)
9 String toString ( int ,int , )
public java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString()
1 String toString (  )
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toHexString(int)
9 String toHexString ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.compare(int,int)
9 int compare ( int ,int , )
public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
4161 int compareTo ( Object , )
public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Integer)
1 int compareTo ( Integer , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.decode(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
9 Integer decode ( String , )
static void java.lang.Integer.getChars(int,int,char[])
8 void getChars ( int ,int ,char[] , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
9 Integer valueOf ( String ,int , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int)
9 Integer valueOf ( int , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
9 Integer valueOf ( String , )
public int java.lang.Integer.intValue()
1 int intValue (  )
public static int java.lang.Integer.reverse(int)
9 int reverse ( int , )
static int java.lang.Integer.stringSize(int)
8 int stringSize ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.reverseBytes(int)
9 int reverseBytes ( int , )
public byte java.lang.Integer.byteValue()
1 byte byteValue (  )
public double java.lang.Integer.doubleValue()
1 double doubleValue (  )
public float java.lang.Integer.floatValue()
1 float floatValue (  )
public long java.lang.Integer.longValue()
1 long longValue (  )
public short java.lang.Integer.shortValue()
1 short shortValue (  )
public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
9 int parseInt ( String , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
9 int parseInt ( String ,int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.bitCount(int)
9 int bitCount ( int , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
9 Integer getInteger ( String ,Integer , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,int)
9 Integer getInteger ( String ,int , )
public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String)
9 Integer getInteger ( String , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.highestOneBit(int)
9 int highestOneBit ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.lowestOneBit(int)
9 int lowestOneBit ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int)
9 int numberOfLeadingZeros ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int)
9 int numberOfTrailingZeros ( int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateLeft(int,int)
9 int rotateLeft ( int ,int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateRight(int,int)
9 int rotateRight ( int ,int , )
public static int java.lang.Integer.signum(int)
9 int signum ( int , )
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(int)
9 String toBinaryString ( int , )
public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(int)
9 String toOctalString ( int , )
private static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toUnsignedString(int,int)
10 String toUnsignedString ( int ,int , )
```

I have modified in-build toGenericString() to suit your needs :

```
package SO;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class jr {
    // Modifiers that can be applied to a method in source code
    private static final int LANGUAGE_MODIFIERS = Modifier.PUBLIC | Modifier.PROTECTED | Modifier.PRIVATE
        | Modifier.ABSTRACT | Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL | Modifier.SYNCHRONIZED | Modifier.NATIVE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    jr j = new jr();

    String str = "java.lang.Integer";

    Class<?> cls = Class.forName(str);
    j.print(cls);
    }

    /*
     * Displays the Methods of the given class. The items displayed depends on
     * the options entered.
     * 
     * @param cl The class to be displayed
     */
    public void methods(Class cl) {
    // Get the Methods of the Class cl
    Method[] me = cl.getDeclaredMethods();

    for (Method x : me) {
        String parameterType = "";
        System.out.println("simple   :" + x);
        System.out.println("generic  :" + x.toGenericString());
        System.out.println("modified :" + modifiedToGenericString(x));
        ;

    }
    }

    public String modifiedToGenericString(Method m) {
    try {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int mod = m.getModifiers() & LANGUAGE_MODIFIERS;
        if (mod != 0) {
        sb.append(Modifier.toString(mod) + " ");
        }
        Type[] typeparms = m.getTypeParameters();
        if (typeparms.length > 0) {
        boolean first = true;
        sb.append("<");
        for (Type typeparm : typeparms) {
            if (!first)
            sb.append(",");
            if (typeparm instanceof Class)
            sb.append(((Class) typeparm).getSimpleName());
            else
            sb.append(typeparm.toString());
            first = false;
        }
        sb.append("> ");
        }

        Type genRetType = m.getGenericReturnType();
        sb.append(((genRetType instanceof Class) ? ((Class) genRetType).getSimpleName() : genRetType.toString())
            + " ");

        // sb.append((m.getDeclaringClass()) + ".");
        sb.append(m.getName() + "(");
        Type[] params = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
        for (int j = 0; j < params.length; j++) {
        sb.append((params[j] instanceof Class) ? ((Class) params[j]) : (params[j].toString()));
        if (j < (params.length - 1))
            sb.append(",");
        }
        sb.append(")");
        Type[] exceptions = m.getGenericExceptionTypes();
        if (exceptions.length > 0) {
        sb.append(" throws ");
        for (int k = 0; k < exceptions.length; k++) {
            sb.append((exceptions[k] instanceof Class) ? ((Class) exceptions[k]).getSimpleName()
                : exceptions[k].toString());
            if (k < (exceptions.length - 1))
            sb.append(",");
        }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "<" + e + ">";
    }
    }

    /*
     * Displays the information about the class. Uses the options to filter
     * which information is printed.
     * 
     * @param cl The class to be displayed
     */
    public void print(Class cl) {
    System.out.println("\nMETHODS:");
    methods(cl);
    }
}
```

**With following output:**

```
METHODS:
simple   :public int java.lang.Integer.hashCode()
generic  :public int java.lang.Integer.hashCode()
modified :public int hashCode()
simple   :public boolean java.lang.Integer.equals(java.lang.Object)
generic  :public boolean java.lang.Integer.equals(java.lang.Object)
modified :public boolean equals(class java.lang.Object)
simple   :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int)
generic  :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int)
modified :public static String toString(int)
simple   :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int,int)
generic  :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int,int)
modified :public static String toString(int,int)
simple   :public java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString()
generic  :public java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString()
modified :public String toString()
simple   :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toHexString(int)
generic  :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toHexString(int)
modified :public static String toHexString(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.compare(int,int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.compare(int,int)
modified :public static int compare(int,int)
simple   :public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
generic  :public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Object)
modified :public int compareTo(class java.lang.Object)
simple   :public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Integer)
generic  :public int java.lang.Integer.compareTo(java.lang.Integer)
modified :public int compareTo(class java.lang.Integer)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.decode(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.decode(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
modified :public static Integer decode(class java.lang.String) throws NumberFormatException
simple   :static void java.lang.Integer.getChars(int,int,char[])
generic  :static void java.lang.Integer.getChars(int,int,char[])
modified :static void getChars(int,int,class [C)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
modified :public static Integer valueOf(class java.lang.String,int) throws NumberFormatException
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int)
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int)
modified :public static Integer valueOf(int)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.valueOf(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
modified :public static Integer valueOf(class java.lang.String) throws NumberFormatException
simple   :public int java.lang.Integer.intValue()
generic  :public int java.lang.Integer.intValue()
modified :public int intValue()
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.reverse(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.reverse(int)
modified :public static int reverse(int)
simple   :static int java.lang.Integer.stringSize(int)
generic  :static int java.lang.Integer.stringSize(int)
modified :static int stringSize(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.reverseBytes(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.reverseBytes(int)
modified :public static int reverseBytes(int)
simple   :public byte java.lang.Integer.byteValue()
generic  :public byte java.lang.Integer.byteValue()
modified :public byte byteValue()
simple   :public double java.lang.Integer.doubleValue()
generic  :public double java.lang.Integer.doubleValue()
modified :public double doubleValue()
simple   :public float java.lang.Integer.floatValue()
generic  :public float java.lang.Integer.floatValue()
modified :public float floatValue()
simple   :public long java.lang.Integer.longValue()
generic  :public long java.lang.Integer.longValue()
modified :public long longValue()
simple   :public short java.lang.Integer.shortValue()
generic  :public short java.lang.Integer.shortValue()
modified :public short shortValue()
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
modified :public static int parseInt(class java.lang.String) throws NumberFormatException
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.parseInt(java.lang.String,int) throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
modified :public static int parseInt(class java.lang.String,int) throws NumberFormatException
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.bitCount(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.bitCount(int)
modified :public static int bitCount(int)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer)
modified :public static Integer getInteger(class java.lang.String,class java.lang.Integer)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,int)
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String,int)
modified :public static Integer getInteger(class java.lang.String,int)
simple   :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String)
generic  :public static java.lang.Integer java.lang.Integer.getInteger(java.lang.String)
modified :public static Integer getInteger(class java.lang.String)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.highestOneBit(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.highestOneBit(int)
modified :public static int highestOneBit(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.lowestOneBit(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.lowestOneBit(int)
modified :public static int lowestOneBit(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(int)
modified :public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(int)
modified :public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateLeft(int,int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateLeft(int,int)
modified :public static int rotateLeft(int,int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateRight(int,int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.rotateRight(int,int)
modified :public static int rotateRight(int,int)
simple   :public static int java.lang.Integer.signum(int)
generic  :public static int java.lang.Integer.signum(int)
modified :public static int signum(int)
simple   :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(int)
generic  :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString(int)
modified :public static String toBinaryString(int)
simple   :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(int)
generic  :public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toOctalString(int)
modified :public static String toOctalString(int)
simple   :private static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toUnsignedString(int,int)
generic  :private static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toUnsignedString(int,int)
modified :private static String toUnsignedString(int,int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
System.out.println(x.toString().replaceAll("([\\w_$]+\\.)+", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I basically stole the `toString` method from `method` and made a couple of minor adjustments...

It now dumps output like `public static String toString(int,int)`

```
public class TestReflection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        TestReflection tr = new TestReflection();
        String str = "java.lang.Integer";
        Class cls = Class.forName(str);
        tr.print(cls);
    }

    /*
     * Displays the Methods of the given class. The items displayed depends on
     * the options entered.
     *
     * @param    cl    The class to be displayed
     */
    public void methods(Class cl) {
        // Get the Methods of the Class cl
        Method[] me = cl.getDeclaredMethods();

        for (Method x : me) {
            System.out.println(toString(x));
        }
    }

    /*
     * Displays the information about the class. Uses the options to filter which
     * information is printed.
     *
     * @param    cl    The class to be displayed
     */
    public void print(Class cl) {
        System.out.println("\nMETHODS:");
        methods(cl);
    }

    public static String getTypeName(Class<?> type) {
        if (type.isArray()) {
            try {
                Class<?> cl = type;
                int dimensions = 0;
                while (cl.isArray()) {
                    dimensions++;
                    cl = cl.getComponentType();
                }
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                sb.append(cl.getName());
                for (int i = 0; i < dimensions; i++) {
                    sb.append("[]");
                }
                return sb.toString();
            } catch (Throwable e) { /*FALLTHRU*/ }
        }
        return type.getName();
    }

    private String toString(Method method) {
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int mod = method.getModifiers() & Modifier.methodModifiers();
            if (mod != 0) {
                sb.append(Modifier.toString(mod)).append(' ');
            }
            sb.append(method.getReturnType().getSimpleName()).append(' ');
            sb.append(method.getName()).append('(');
            Class<?>[] params = method.getParameterTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < params.length; j++) {
                sb.append(getTypeName(params[j]));
                if (j < (params.length - 1)) {
                    sb.append(',');
                }
            }
            sb.append(')');
            Class<?>[] exceptions = method.getExceptionTypes();
            if (exceptions.length > 0) {
                sb.append(" throws ");
                for (int k = 0; k < exceptions.length; k++) {
                    sb.append(exceptions[k].getName());
                    if (k < (exceptions.length - 1)) {
                        sb.append(',');
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "<" + e + ">";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I was hoping for a simpler way but I guess not, silly Java!!

Comment: @MadProgrammer :  checkout toGenericString() . It does the same thing.

Comment: @PriyankDoshi To according to my tests, it prints `public static java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString(int,int)` - It would seem that this is the "generics" version.  It might be better to rip this off instead though ;)

Comment: Yeah you are right.It prints  :public void java.util.ArrayList.add(int,E)'

Comment: In the installation location of the JDK there is a `source.zip` file which contains all the (public) available source (Java) files.  In Netbeans you can [ctrl+left click] and object reference to move to the source, I'm sure you can do it with Eclipse, I just don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the ideas. I took some of your suggestions and changed around a few things. Here is my code:

/*
    * Displays the Methods of the given class. The items displayed depends on 
    * the options entered.
    *
    * @param    cl    The class to be displayed
    */ 
    public void methods(Class cl)
    {
        // Get the Methods of the Class cl
        Method[] me = cl.getDeclaredMethods();

```
    // If all modifiers are selected, print all Methods
    if(allMods == true)
    {
        for(Method x : me)
        {            
            //System.out.println(INDENT + x);
            printMethod(x);
        }
    } 

    // Print Methods, only displaying those items with the modifiers that 
    // were selected
    else
    {
        for(Method x : me)
        {            
            String str = x.toString();

            if((str.startsWith("private") && p == true) ||
                (str.startsWith("public") && u == true) ||
                (str.startsWith("protected") && P == true))
            {
                //System.out.println(INDENT + x);
                printMethod(x);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int)
public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int)
public static int bitCount(int)
public boolean equals(Object)
public String toString()
public static String toString(int, int)
public static String toString(int)
public int hashCode()
public static int reverseBytes(int)
public volatile int compareTo(Object)
public int compareTo(Integer)
public byte byteValue()
public short shortValue()
public int intValue()
public long longValue()
public float floatValue()
public double doubleValue()
public static Integer valueOf(String)
public static Integer valueOf(int)
public static Integer valueOf(String, int)
public static int reverse(int)
static int stringSize(int)
public static String toHexString(int)
static void getChars(int, int, char[])
public static Integer decode(String)
public static int compare(int, int)
public static int parseInt(String)
public static int parseInt(String, int)
public static String toOctalString(int)
public static String toBinaryString(int)
private static String toUnsignedString(int, int)
public static Integer getInteger(String)
public static Integer getInteger(String, int)
public static Integer getInteger(String, Integer)
public static int highestOneBit(int)
public static int lowestOneBit(int)
public static int rotateLeft(int, int)
public static int rotateRight(int, int)
public static int signum(int)
```